# Angular doesn't find element by id

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor

I'm learning Angular and I'm building a simple calendar component. I want to give an id to the "td" elements and give them classes based on the backend data. If they are reserved by the customer I will give a class "reserved" and then make the background red.
My code looks like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let week of createArrays()">
    <td *ngFor="let day of week" id="{{ 'id_' + day }}">{{ day }}</td>
</tr>
```

This will look like:

```
<td _ngcontent-ehf-c16="" id="id_21">21</td>
```

Then in the component.ts I use the service to get the reserved dates and save them in a Set.

```
  closeDates(): any {
    for (const date of this.reserved) {
      if (date.getMonth() === this.date.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() === this.date.getFullYear()) {
        document.querySelector(`#id_${date.getDate()}`).classList.add('reserved');
      }
    }
  }
```

After the function runs it still doesn't have the reserved class.
If I run the same querySelector code in the console it finds the element and makes the background red.

Comment: Where do you run your closeDates method ? it can be that component tempalate is not yet rendered.

Comment: Where do you call the `closeDates()` method from? I assume you have a subscription somewhere where `this.reserved` is assigned it's value? How is the subscription related to `closeDates()`?

Comment: If I console log the element in the loop it will find it, so it has already loaded. But the classList won't update. I tried to run it with a button added to the page, with the (click), and still no luck.

Comment: @bernat97 ok, so the best choice here is gotta be next:
1. Remove the querySelector and stuff
2. On your td add line [class.reserved]="reservedDatesMap[id]"
3. Create some method to updated reservedDatesMap in format like 
const reservedDatesMap = this.reserved.reduce((acc, date) => {
   const day = date.getDate();
   const isReserved = date.getMonth() === this.date.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() === this.date.getFullYear();
   return {...acc, [day]: isReserved};
}, {});
This will make angular update class instead of you.

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko post this as an answer as this is the correct way to go

Comment: @bernat97 followup to my previous comment - const reservedDatesMap should be exposed to component class variables - so somewhere you need to do this.reservedDatesMap = ...(previous comment stuff)

Comment: Great, I can see my comment got deleted, why, because I said this is not how you use Angular? Did I offend someone? Was it considered as spam? No idea. But the fact is, _this is not how Angular works_. You don't give IDs in Angular, you don't `querySelector` or `getElementById`. This is nonsense. If you persist, you will simply never make it. You are trying to `getElementById` on elements that Angular _has not generated in the view yet_. You are using `.classList.add` on elements that haven't been generated yet, instead of using Angular's `[ngClass]` attribute.

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko Thanks! It's finally working!

Comment: @JeremyThille I did not delete your comment. Actually, it helped me. I'm a beginner at Angular and I didn't know that I can't use querySelector.

Comment: I know you didn't delete my comment, because you can't. Some moderator did, for some unknown reason. I was only stating that's not how angular works, and that must have been considered as insulting and deleted (?) Anyhow, Angular generates the view (HTML) from data, and re-generates it when the data changes. That's why using `getElementById` and other JS methods don't belong here. You don't give an ID then select the element to change its class. You _generate_ the element's class from data.